# Как поменять местами цифры в строке?

Tags: php

Нужно 08/12/2015 16:00 превратить в 12/08/2015 16:00, то есть поменять местами 08 и 12, как это сделать?

Comment: `08/12/2015 16:00` внесите ясность это дата время? Вам необходимо форматировать формат выводимой Даты?

Answer (score 5):

```
$str = '08/12/2015 16:00';

$time = strtotime($str); // Преобразовываем дату в Unix Time

echo date('d/m/Y H:i', $time); // Печатаем как нам удобно

# Результат: 12/08/2015 16:00
```

Comment: А Вы уверены, что у автора вопроса в исходной строке 08 — это месяц, а 12 — число, а не наоборот? Мы же не знаем, откуда и каким образом он эту строку получает.

Comment: @Yaant именно для этих целей я и задал уточняющий вопрос в коментарии

Comment: @Yaant строка похожа на `datetime`, мой ответ обрабатывает именно его. Если это не `datetime`, то пускай автор формирует правильно свои мысли - здесь нет экстрасенсов.

Comment: @Bald56rus О, я почему-то не заметил Вашего комментария, когда писал свой, хотя он вроде как был написан раньше моего. :)

Comment: @mix Ну, ведь с тем же успехом можно было и предположить, что автору как раз и надо преобразовать строку, "похожую на `datetime`" к такому формату, который далее позволит использовать `strtotime()`. Поэтому крайне полезно было бы в ответе сразу оговорить границы применимости этого ответа. :)

Comment: @Yaant `datetime` как имеет формат не `d/m/Y...`, а `m/d/Y`, отсюда несложно предположить, что автор имел ввиду на самом деле. В свои годы и я сталкивался с этой проблемой, поэтому, еще раз повторюсь, нужно конкретнее описывать свою проблему, если это не соблюдать, то, вполне возможно, что люди не дадут удовлетворяющего ответа на твой вопрос.

Comment: @mix Так о чем и речь. Возможно, автору надо преобразовать строку `m/d/y` в более привычный нам формат `d/m/y` для показа пользователю (но почему тогда не еще более привычный `d.m.y`?). Либо, наоборот, откуда-то он получает строку формата `d/m/y` (скажем, парсингом стороннего сайта), и ему надо получить из этого полноценную дату, чтобы дальше делать с ней что-то своё. В вопросе данных, чтобы однозначно выбрать одну их этих версий, нет. Поэтому, если Вы выбираете какую-то одну из них для своего ответа, стоит это явно указать, чтобы автор мог сразу понять, тот ли этот путь, который ему нужен.:)

Comment: @Yaant вы так и будете все возможные варианты рассматривать? Очень многое возможно, рассмотрите все, у меня нет желания участвовать в этом процессе.

Comment: @Yaant а из моего ответа наглядно видно что есть что. Например из комментированного текста видно, что я преобразовываю строку во время, если автору нужно не время, он проигнорирует мой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "08/12/2015 16:00";
$date   = explode(' ', $string);
$result = explode('/', $date[0]);
$result = $result[1].'/'.$result[0].'/'.$result[2].' '.$date[1];
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще, вариант с регулярным выражением, более применимый в случае, если в строке после указанного текста может идти дополнительный текст.

```
 preg_replace('/^(\d{2}\/)(\d{2}\/)/','$2$1','08/12/2015 16:00');
```

**UPD:**
Приведенная Вами строка в качестве примера крайне смахивает на объект `DateTime` если это так то тогда лучше воспользоваться решением предложенным @mix, т.е. преобразуем строку в объект `DateTime` и форматируем как Вам необходимо

Comment: ну зачем же так, ведь эта строка явно `DateTime` лучше сделать как советует @mix

Comment: @Bald56rus, поэтому я и сказал - _еще вариант_, а не единственно правильный :-) выбор должен быть всегда ;-)

Comment: это *темная сторона силы* ;), не надо учить такому

Comment: @Bald56rus, если кто-то не умеет пользоваться регулярными выражениями, это не значит, что ими нельзя пользоваться :-) Код задачу выполняет - значит все номально

Comment: @Bald56rus, вообще странно получать минусы за правильное решение :-)

Comment: каюсь, каюсь про регулярки верно подмечено:D,  но использовать их для форматирования даты повторюсь: *это путь на темную сторону силы* и кстати минус не мой ;)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32725/discussion-between-grundy-and-bald56rus).